# Designing a deck of cards using a linked list

Tags: java

The objective of this program is to design a deck of cards using a linked list.
My codes does not print anything out when it runs.
Heres my code below

Node Class:

```
public class Node
{
private Comparable data;
private Node next;
public Node()
{
next = null;
}
public Node(Comparable c)
{
data = c;
next = null;
}
public Node(Comparable c, Node n)
{
data = c;
next = n;
}
public Comparable getData()
{
return data;
}
public void setData(Comparable c)
{
data = c;
}
public Node getNext()
{
return next;
}
public void setNext(Node n)
{
next = n;
}

}
```

LinkedList class:

```
public class LinkedList
{
private Node first = null;
private Node current = null;
private Node pre = null;
public boolean isEmpty()
{
return true;
}
public boolean contains(Comparable item)
{
current = first;
pre = null;
while ((current != null)&&(current.getData().compareTo(item) < 0))
{
pre = current;
current = current.getNext();
}
return ((current != null) && (current.getData().compareTo(item) == 0));
}
public int size()
{
int count = 0;
current = first;
pre = null;
while (current != null)
{
pre = current;
current = current.getNext();
count++;
}
return count;

}
public void add(Comparable c)
{

Node temp = new Node(c);
if (pre == null)
{
first = temp;
}
else
{
pre.setNext(temp);
}
temp.setNext(current);
current = temp;
}
public void remove(Comparable c)
{
if (pre == null)
{
first = first.getNext();
}
else
{
current = current.getNext();
if (pre == null)
{
first = current;
}
else
{
pre.setNext(current);
}

}

}
public void clear()
{
first = null;
}
public void print()
{
Node current = first;
while (current != null)
{
System.out.println(current.getData());
current = current.getNext();
}
}
}
```

Card class:

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card>
{
private int rank;
private int suit;
public Card(int suit, int rank)
{
this.rank = rank;
this.suit = suit;
}
public int getRank()
{
return rank;
}
public int getSuit()
{
return suit;
}
public String toString()
{
switch(suit)
{
case 1:
switch(rank)
{
case 11: return "Jack of Hearts";
case 12: return "Queen of Hearts";
case 13: return "King of Hearts";
case 14: return "Ace of Hearts";
default: return rank + " of Hearts";
}

case 2:
switch(rank)
{
case 11: return "Jack of Diamonds";
case 12: return "Queen of Diamonds";
case 13: return "King of Diamonds";
case 14: return "Ace of Diamonds";
default: return rank + " of Diamonds";
}
case 3:
switch(rank)
{
case 11: return "Jack of Clubs";
case 12: return "Queen of Clubs";
case 13: return "King of Clubs";
case 14: return "Ace of Clubs";
default: return rank + " of Clubs";
}
case 4:
switch(rank)
{
case 11: return "Jack of Spades";
case 12: return "Queen of Spades";
case 13: return "King of Spades";
case 14: return "Ace of Spades";
default: return rank + " of Spades";
}
}
return null;
}
public int compareTo(Card a)
{
if (this.rank < a.rank)
{
return -1;
}
if (this.rank > a.rank)
{
return 1;
}
if (this.rank == a.rank)
{
if (this.suit < a.suit)
{   
return -1;
}
if (this.suit > a.suit)
{
return 1;
}
}

return 0;
}
}
```

CardDeck class - a linked list of card:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class CardDeck
{
private LinkedList cards;
private int numCards;
public void Deck()
{
for (int a = 1; a <= 4; a++)
{
for (int b = 1; b <= 14; b++)
{
cards.add(new Card(a,B)/>);
}
}
}

public void drawFromDeck()
{
Random rand = new Random();
int index = rand.nextInt(cards.size());
cards.remove(index);
numCards--;
}
public int getTotalCard()
{
return cards.size();
}
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
LinkedList myList = new LinkedList();
CardDeck myCards = new CardDeck();
myCards.Deck();
myList.print();
}
```

Comment: Your code is without any indentations making it all left justified and almost impossible to read, understand and debug. Please re-format your posted code by giving it proper indentations, usually 4 spaces per block, and making sure that all code on the same block is on the same indentation level. Your cooperation in this would be greatly appreciated and will likely improve your chances of getting a decent and prompt answer.

Comment: please fix your formatting

Comment: You're creating a LinkedList myList variable within main that does nothing and serves no purpose -- why? Don't create code without purpose, and so get rid of this wasted variable and don't try to call print on it as it holds nothing. Instead you should print out the contents of your myCards variable.

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, `myList`, which you are printing out, is never modified past the constructor being called. If you want to print out the contents of `myCard`, you need to either put the print statements in a method in that class, and call that method to print the deck contents, or make a getter for `cards` and print it outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect program.
cards.add(new Card(a,B)/>); this line should throw an exception as
you have not initialized cards.
Its null.